# Переключение между несколькими ListFragment с помощью bottomNavigation bar

Tags: android-studio, listview, android-fragment

Суть проблемы:

Предположим, у меня есть 2 `ListFragment`:

- список городов
- список пород собак

Запускается приложение, пользователь сразу видит список городов, и с помощью нижней панельки может переключиться на просмотр списка пород собак.

Как правильно реализовать вызов `ListFragment` в таком случае?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для реализации Вашей цели подойдут либо TabbedActivity, либо Bottom Navigation Activity. Рассмотрю решение на последней. 
Пусть `CityFragment` - ваш фрагмент с городами, а `DogFragment` - с собаками.

**1)** В Android Studio File -> New -> Activity -> Bottom Navigation Activity - создайте Activity.

**2)** В menu/navigation.xml (разметка кнопок у Вашей Activity) установите id для каждого item'а:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_city"
    android:title="Города" /> <!--- тут нужно использовать @string, но я упростил -->

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_dog"
    android:title="Собаки" />
```

**3)** В .xml файле Вашей Activity добавьте FrameLayout

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    > <!--- Вместо fragment - ваш id -->
```

**4)** Переходите в класс Activity. Здесь нужен метод `onNavigationItemSelected`.
Он обрабатывает, какую кнопку пользователь нажал и, в зависимости от этого, загружает нужный фрагмент. Замените код, который был создан Android Studio, на этот:

```
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_city: // если города, то фрагмент городов
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment, new CityFragment());
                transaction.commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_dog: // если собаки, то фрагмент собак
                transaction.add(R.id.fragment, new DogFragment(), TAG_FRAGMENT_DOG);
                transaction.commit();
                return true;

        }

        return false;
    }
};
```

Вот и все, у меня это решение работает, должно и у Вас.